# Is there a way to use Firebase with a ShareExtension without AppGroups

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore, share-extension

I'm setting up a `shareExtension` in iOS and want to use the `FirebaseSDK` to upload data direct instead of using `AppGroups`. This works as expected, but after 1 hour the UserToken get's invalidated and i can't reach the `Firestore` Backend anymore.

I'm using the `FirebaseSDK (6.2.0)` and enabled Keychain sharing to access the current signedIn User. I have the same `Google-Plist` in the MainApp and the `shareExtension`. The data gets also uploaded correctly from the `shareExtension` and was also updated via the `snapshotListener` in the MainApp.

Relevant code in the MainApp

```swift
    lazy var db = Firestore.firestore()
    //TEAMID form the Apple Developer Portal
    let accessGroup = "TEAMID.de.debug.fireAuthExample"

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        do {
            try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("\(accessGroup)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
        }
        guard let user = Auth.auth().currentUser else {
            self.statusLabel.text = "user get's lost"
            return
        }
        statusLabel.text = "UserID: \(user.uid)"
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        db.collection("DummyCollection").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
            if let err = error {
                print(err.localizedDescription)
            }
            guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.dbCountLabel.text = "\(snapshot.count)"
            }
        }

    }

        func signIN(){
        // https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/single-sign-on
        do {
            try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup("\(accessGroup)")
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
        }
        Auth.auth().signInAnonymously { (result, error) in
            if let err = error{
                print(err.localizedDescription)
                return
            }
            print("UserID: \(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid)")
            }
        }
    }
 }
```

Code in the shareExtension:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FirebaseApp.app() == nil {
            FirebaseApp.configure()
        }
        do {
            try Auth.auth().useUserAccessGroup(accessGroup)
        } catch let error as NSError {
            print("Error changing user access group: %@", error)
        }
        tempUser = Auth.auth().currentUser

        if tempUser != nil {
            userIDLabel.text = "UserID: \(tempUser!.uid)"
            doneButton.isEnabled = true

            db.collection("DummyCollection").addSnapshotListener { (querySnapshot, error) in
                if let err = error {
                    print(err.localizedDescription)
                }
                guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {
                    return
                }
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.dataCountLabel.text = "\(snapshot.count)"
                }
            }
        } else {
            // No user exists in the access group
            self.navigationItem.title = "No User"
        }
    }
```

I expect that this should be possible, but the Token gets somehow invalid in the MainApp and i could not reach the Firestore backend.

6.2.0 - [Firebase/Auth][I-AUT000003] Token auto-refresh re-scheduled in 01:00 because of error on previous refresh attempt.

6.2.0 - [Firebase/Firestore][I-FST000001] Could not reach Cloud Firestore backend. Connection failed 1 times. Most recent error: An internal error has occurred, print and inspect the error details for more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering my own question: This should be fixed in the next release (Firebase 6.4.0) [Details can be found in this PR 3239](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/3239).